# How to access a value in a dictionary which is inside a list and modify one value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate a list of dictionaries with a `for` loop in this way:

```
my_list = []

while True:
    print("Welcome, choose number 1")
    print("1.- Coke")
    numb = input()

    if numb is "1":
        for l in my_list:
            if l["product"] is "coke":
                l["count"] += 1 
            else:
                Coke = {"product":"coke", "count":1, "price":17.5}
                my_list.append(Coke)
```

What I expect the code to do is to search in each dictionary inside the list to find a match and add 1 to `count` value or in case such dictionary don't exist to create it and append it, but when running the code it just keeps `my_list` empty.

I've tried to delete the iteration and go directly to the creation of the dict which it does without a problem, but when doing the iteration I got no result.

Comment: Reference it by index and then by key! `my_list[list_index][dict_key]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in Python we use `==` to compare with a literal, and if you use `is`, Python will give a `SyntaxWarning`. Second, in your code, if `my_list` is empty, then the code after `for l in my_list` won't be executed because it won't iterate over anything. So the code can be:

```py
my_list = []

while True:
    print("Welcome, choose number 1")
    print("1.- Coke")
    numb = input()

    if numb == "1":
        for l in my_list:
            if l["product"] == "coke":
                l["count"] += 1
                break
        else:
            Coke = {"product": "coke", "count": 1, "price": 17.5}
            my_list.append(Coke)
```

Where the `else` after the `for` means "if the `for` exited without a `break`".
Hope it helps you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use list_name[list_index][dict_key] to access a value within a dictionary in list of dictionaries provided the list index and dict key is known

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is

Initially, my_list is empty so the for loop is not executing at all.So your final result will be always an empty list. Try including a single element in the my_list

```
my_list = [{"product":"coke", "count":1, "price":17.5}]

while True:
    print("Welcome, choose number 1")
    print("1.- Coke")
    numb = input()

    if numb is "1":
        for l in my_list:
            if l["product"] is "coke":
                l["count"] += 1 
            else:
                Coke = {"product":"coke", "count":1, "price":17.5}
                my_list.append(Coke)
```

Try this will solve your problem.